# Ruby on Rails assets not being precompiled on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a project that works in the local development environment but breaks when it is uploaded to Heroku. When visiting my project on Heroku, I notice that I get 404 responses from the server saying that it could not find my `css` and `js` files. I have done some searching and found out that Heroku is not precompiling my assets. The project will work fine until Heroku puts my project to sleep. Upon waking the project in Heroku, the `css` and `js` are broken.

The project is using Rails 4.2.4, I have made sure to to include `config.serve_static_assets = true` in my `config/application.rb` and `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` in my Gemfile.

The `css` and `js` only breaks when Heroku puts the project to sleep due to inactivity. Does anyone know how to have Heroku automatically precompile assets when it is awaken from sleep?

Comment: if my answer was helpful do not forget to mark it as accepted answer, this way other people of the community will continue helping you.

Comment: If my answer was helpful I too would like to be up voted and @Ferrazeth if you would please click accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues before, my best bet was to precompile in local and then push to heroku. Configure your production.rb as follows:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
config.assets.compile = false
```

then in your console precompile as follows:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will precompile everything in `public/assets` commit your changes and push to heroku.

Also reset your assets cache for avoid any inconsistence:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

The above will force all your `public/assets` directory to rebuild when you run precompile command.

If your issue is with assets recompilation my answer should solve it, if you still have issues then you are doing something wrong or the issue does not have anything to do with assets precompilation.

We set the configuration values of above to false because now you are sending the precompiled files to the repo, so we do not serve static files nor fallback assets pipeline if something is missing, we are going everything in local.

Comment: I have done this but now my assets don't show up on my heroku. All of the images are missing.

Comment: Ho it may be because there is some sort of old assets cache, try `rake assets:clean` this will force all your `public/assets` directory to rebuild when you precompile. Make sure you pass `RAILS_ENV=production` when precompiling, also do not forget to commit your changes

Comment: I ran `rake assets:clean` however the images are still not showing up. Also in your original answer, what is the reason for setting both values to `false`?

Comment: Check the answer again

Comment: After doing some searching online I found that 'config.serve_static_files' must be set to `true` in order for rails to access assets in the `public` folder. Is it possible to have this set to `true` without my website breaking on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

#### application.rb

By default Rails 4 will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into config/application.rb and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

#### production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

#### Command Line

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Make sure the images are in the /public folder.

[Reference here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)

Comment: RAILS 5 UPDATE: Previous versions of Rails required you to add a gem to your project rails_12factor to enable static asset serving and logging on Heroku. If you are deploying a new application this gem is not needed. If you are upgrading an existing application you can remove this gem provided you have the appropriate configuration in your config/environments/production.rb file:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

Comment: # config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end